# recursively encrypt property which ends with 'id' or '_id'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to encrypt and decrypt recursively any key which ends with `id` or `_id`.
It should loop through all the `key` inside passed `array` or `object` or `array of objects` to search for the key and encrypt it. Finally it will return encrypted data.

I tried below function, but it's not working.

```
 const { encrypt, decrypt } = require('./cryptor')


 const encryptIt = async function (data) {
    encryptor(data)
    return data
 }

function encryptor(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(el => {
            encryptIt(el)
        })
    } else if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
        for(let key in data)
            encryptIt(key)
    } else if (data.endsWith('id') || data.endsWith('_id')) {
        data = encryptor(data)
    }
    return data
}

const a = {
    "id": 2343,
    "profile_id": 27883,
    "name": "david"
}
async function test(){
    try {
        console.log(await encryptIt(a))
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
test()
```

error that I am getting.

> (node:812) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

It should return encrypted data, whether passed was `array`, `object` or `array of objects` their structure should not change. 
Only key should be encrypted. like

```
{
  "id": "zHaw",
  "profile_id": "sdfw",
  "name": "david"
}
```

For encryption and decryption I am using some algorithm but to simulate one can use [base62](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base62) `encode()` and `decode()`.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs) to show the issue happening?

Comment: Why you call `encrypt(a)` ? With input is `a` object, what is your expect output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with help of Radu's answer that could have been a comment though ;), but I don't know if it would work for all cases. 
Please suggest if someone see any problem with this approach.

```
const { encrypt, decrypt } = require('./cryptor')


 const encryptIt = async function (data) {
    encryptor(data)
    return data
}
function encryptor(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(el => {
            encryptor(el)
        })
    } else if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
        for(let key in data) {
            if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
                encryptor(data[key])
              } else if(typeof data[key] === 'object' && data[key] !== null){
                encryptor(data[key])
              } else if (key === 'id' || key.endsWith('_id')) {
                data[key] = encrypt(data[key])
              }
        }
    }
    return data
}
const a = {
    "id": 2343,
    "hell": [
      {
         "my_id": 23434, 
         "h": {
            "x_id": 3344
          }
      },
      {
         "your_id": 43434
      }

    ],
    "name": "david"
}
async function test(){
    try{
    console.dir(await encryptIt(a), { depth: 5 } )
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
test()
```

Answer (score 1):

For data that is not `Array` or `object` and ends in `id` or `_id` you are recursively calling `encryptor`

You should end the recursion for that branch

```
const { encrypt, decrypt } = require('./cryptor')


const encryptIt = async function (data) {
    encryptor(data)
    return data
 }

function encryptor(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(el => {
            encryptIt(el)
        })
    } else if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
        for(let key in data)
           if( key.endsWith('id') || key.endsWith('_id')
            data[key] = encrypt(data[key])
    }
    return data
}

const a = {
    "id": 2343,
    "name": "david"
}
async function test(){
    try {
        console.log(await encryptIt(a))
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
test()
```

Comment: You are missing `)` on if inside for. Also, It's not working if passed object has a key valued array of objects. `{ "data" : [{"y_id": 234}, {"m_id": 343}]}`